# How can I get Snippet in TextSearchReport in V10.4

Tags: documentation

In the help page, there is a column named snippet which is very useful, but I cann't see it when I evaluate the Function `TextSeachReport` on V10.3 or V10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a bug because when the code is executed in the documentation the results don't have the "Snippet" column. Perhaps you should report this to WRI.

As a workaround you can create it yourself.

```
TextSearchReport["ExampleData/Text", "dog"][All, 
   <|"Snippet" -> ContentObject[#["Location"]]["Snippet"], #|> &]
```

Hope this helps.